# What is the proper data structure for modelling censored data in MCMCglmm

Tags: r, mixed-models, mcmc

I would like to create a mixed model to estimate the effect of my treatments (Cort and Pred) on individual behaviour. As my data are right censored (individuals who are not emerge from their shelter within a given time are getting the max. score, here 1200), I intend to use the MCMCglmm package with 'cengaussian' family.

My original data-structure looks like this:

```
   ID Cort Pred repeat. RT_orig 
1   1 NoCH   PA       1     113 
2   2   CH   PA       1      NA 
3   3 NoCH   PA       1      65 
4   4   CH   PA       1    1200 
5   5   CH   PP       1     472 
6   1 NoCH   PA       2     790 
7   2   CH   PA       2      NA 
8   3 NoCH   PA       2       1 
9   4   CH   PA       2      15 
10  5   CH   PP       2    1200 
11  1 NoCH   PA       3      31 
12  2   CH   PA       3     548 
13  3 NoCH   PA       3    1200 
14  4   CH   PA       3    1200 
15  5   CH   PP       3     527
```

and first time I applied the following model

```
model<-MCMCglmm(RT_orig~Cort*Pred+repeat.,
    random=~ID+(0+repeat.|ID), data=xdata, family="cengaussian")
```

However, I ran into this error message:

**`Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'`**

After thorough research on the issue I concluded that my response variable should have two columns, like in a  survival model. But I'm still clueless what the proper data structure should look like.

If I tried to code the censored data in a new column (probably not the right way...)

```
   ID Cort Pred repeat. RT_orig censored
1   1 NoCH   PA       1     113        0
2   2   CH   PA       1      NA       NA
3   3 NoCH   PA       1      65        0
4   4   CH   PA       1    1200        1
5   5   CH   PP       1     472        0
6   1 NoCH   PA       2     790        0
7   2   CH   PA       2      NA        0
8   3 NoCH   PA       2       1        0
9   4   CH   PA       2      15        0
10  5   CH   PP       2    1200        1
11  1 NoCH   PA       3      31        0
12  2   CH   PA       3     548        0
13  3 NoCH   PA       3    1200        1
14  4   CH   PA       3    1200        1
15  5   CH   PP       3     527        0
```

using the following model

```
MCMC.RT<-MCMCglmm(cbind(RT_orig, censored)~Cort*Pred+repeat.,
    random=~ID+(0+repeat.|ID), data=xdata, family="cengaussian")
```

I get this

```
**Error in MCMCglmm(cbind(RT_orig, censored) ~ Cort * Pred + repeat.,  : 
  for censored traits left censoring point must be less than right censoring point**
```

I am pretty sure that I'm very close to the solution, but I could not found any answer to this question enywhere. So I would be very, very gateful if someone could give me an advice on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Lantency data is indeed a problem, which I’m struggling with myself.

So far as I know (I only looked at this very briefly) your data input is good for survival analysis, but not for MCMCglmm. As noted [here](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.5098&rep=rep1&type=pdf), you need to put the minimal and maximal value.

```
data$ymin <- floor (data$y)
data$ymax <- ceiling (data$y)
model <- MCMCglmm (cbind(ymin,ymax) ~Cort*Pred+repeat
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it seems working that way! Although, could you link your source again? I cannot open it from here.